# TYPO3 FluidTYPO3: Missed Flux Icons for Content Elements at TYPO3 Backend

Tags: image, icons, typo3, backend, fluid

Hi I'm using `TYPO3 CMS 6.2.14` with FluidTYPO3 (`flux 7.2.2`, `fluidcontent 4.3.2`and `vhs 2.3.3`). Since the last few TYPO3 installations my Icons for Fluidcontent-Elements are missing in Backend?! I've didn't change the path or sth. else.

Here are my tries, nothing works:

```
<flux:form id="fce6" icon="../typo3conf/ext/mytemplates/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/Icon.gif" wizardTab="FCE" options="{Fluidcontent: {sorting: 106}}">
...
<flux:form id="fce6" options="{Fluidcontent: {sorting: 105}, group: 'FCE', icon: '{f:uri.resource(path: \'Icons/Content/Icon.gif\')}'}">
...
<flux:form id="fce6" options="{icon: '{f:uri.resource(path: \'Icons/Content/Icon.gif\')}'}">
...
<flux:form wizardTab="Bootstrap" id="tabs" icon="{v:extension.path.resources(path: 'Icons/icon-tabs.gif')}">
```

If I inspect the missing Icons in Backend with a developer tool (browser), the Icon is found, so I don't understand it.

```
../typo3conf/ext/mytemplates/Resources/Public/Icons/content/Icon.gif
```

Some sceenshots

### [image: Backend no Icons Fluid TYPO3]

[image: Content Elements FCE 7 fluidcontent FluidTYPO3]

-

The funny thing is, that the Icon is still there, if you're inside the Fluidcontent Element (FCE), see last screenshot (red bar icon):

[image: the icon with the red bar]

**EDIT ::** I was looking in one of my older TYPO3-Projects and the Icons are still there: `flux 7.2.1`, `fluidcontent 4.2.4` and `TYPO3 6.2.15`
Code:

```
<flux:form id="tabsvertical" options="{Fluidcontent: {sorting: 305}, group: 'FCE', icon: '{f:uri.resource(path: \'Icons/Content/Example.gif\')}'}">
```

See screenshot:

[image: icons visible flux fluidcontent]

Comment: I believe this happens because `f:uri.resource()` returns the path relative to the top frames URL (usually `/typo3/backend.php` or similar), but the URL is then used in the frame on the right side, which has a deeper URL (somthing like `/typo3/sysext/cms/layout/db_layout.php?id=123`). A fix would be to use a domain-relative path for the icon instead of a relative one. Some of the vhs-ViewHelpers could help there.

Comment: I've copied this snippet from the Ext. `fluidcontent_bootstrap`: Look at Tabs.html and get: `<flux:form wizardTab="FCE" id="fce6" icon="{v:extension.path.resources(path: 'Icons/Content/Example.gif')}">` but it won't work ..?

Comment: If I leave my flux.form without an icon, I'll see this in the inspector tool: `../../..//typo3conf/ext/fluidcontent/Resources/Public/Icons/Plugin.svg`  -  So there must be sth. wrong with `fluidcontent`. (s. second slash before typo3conf) What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flux supports [convention based icons](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/pull/687) since v.7.2.0.

It means, that for each your template you can have corresponding icon in `Icons` folder, which will be shown automatically.

Example:

Template file `typo3conf\ext\my_ext\Resources\Private\Templates\Content\Grid-1.html` should have an icon `typo3conf\ext\my_ext\Resources\Public\Icons\Content\Grid-1.png`.

See more in [changelog](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/blob/development/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: Hi Viktor, thanks for your answer. Now I see the Icons also at Backend-View (Columns View) [link] (http://postimg.org/image/y5rpagrt3/), but not if I select a new content element (tabs, my first screenshot). Here's the path from backend at devtools again `../../..//typo3conf/ext/my_ext/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/MesseEventsDetail.png` and the template file : `typo3conf/ext/my_ext/Resources/Private/Templates/Content/MesseEventsDetail.html` and my icon `typo3conf/ext/my_ext/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/MesseEventsDetail.png` and in flux `<flux:form id="fce6" wizardTab="FCE">`

Comment: @user2310852 I just took a look at open issue list of Flux, and there is one with [exactly same symptomas](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/943), so you can follow it and see, when it will be fixed or is tehre any workaorund to it.

Comment: Thank you Viktor. Today I've made a new TYPO3-Installation and create a Provider Extension with Builder ... everything is standard FluidTYPO3, but no Icon is visible. I'll follow the issue, hope they'll fix it. Thanks [link](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/151001/ijnzv4cr.png)

Answer (score 0):

I spent some hours with TYPO3 6.2.15 and 7.5 to get icons running. The convention based icons did the job for 6.2.15. Rather than using a f:uri.resource(), which will not work. The flux form configuration is somehow rendered in a special container. E.g. for the "new content elements page". Try to put a var_dump() into the view helper. Best combined with an exit(). The container does not seem to be aware of the extension. That is for 6.2.15 and the current versions of fluid/flux. For 7.5 the 7.2.3 does not produce any reasonable results. I only get /typo3/ as icon path. But the 7.2.4 is expected to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I use this Options Fields for Backend Icons and Grouping.

```
<flux:form.option.group value="Content" />
<flux:form.option.icon value="EXT:ext_name/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/HeroImage.svg" />
```

I also added the `<flux:form.option name="settings.options">` as wrapper around the group and icon Definitions

I'm not using FluidContent but Flux Version 8.2 and TYPO3 8.7.15