# FLUIDTYPO3 Icons are missing (fluidcontent/flux, TYPO3 7.6 LTS)

Tags: icons, typo3, backend, fluid

We had it already .. the missing icons at the fluidcontent-elements at TYPO3 Backend ... ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851230/typo3-fluidtypo3-missed-flux-icons-for-content-elements-at-typo3-backend) f.e.).

Now with `TYPO3 7.6.2 LTS`and the latest `fluidcontent 4.4.0`.

Sometimes the icons are there, but only on specific places, like `Page -> Columns -> Overview`
[image: fluidcontent icons at page/columns view typo3 backend]

But not at the `new content element - wizard`or the `page properties`(images 2+3)

[image: page properties typo3 backend fluid content]
[image: new page content wizard]

At the `new page content wizard` page its the following at inspect tool, Serverpath **and** my directory ..`/homepages/5/d11223344??/htdocs/mydir/typo3conf/ext/myext/Resources/Public/img/icons/MyIcon.svg`

I also create a few Icons at the following folder: `/typo3conf/ext/myext/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/Grid03ThreeCol.png` for `/typo3conf/ext/myext/Resources/Private/Templates/Content/Grid03ThreeCol.html`  - . I've tried png & svg ... nothing.

Is it a fluidtypo3- or a typo3 problem?
How do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

After a few updates from `fluidcontent`or/and `flux`...

Now it works!

Your Template:

```
/typo3conf/ext/yourextension/Resources/Private/Templates/Content/Grid02.html
```

Your Icon:

```
   /typo3conf/ext/yourextension/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/Grid02.svg
```

... the images ..

[image: fluidstyledcontent]

and

[image: new file]

and

[image: backend]

Answer (score 0):

Open your /typo3conf/ext/myext/Resources/Private/Templates/Content/Grid03ThreeCol.html File and in find that icon path.

it will call from below line. Modify your icon path as per below code:

```
<flux:form id="" options="{group: '', icon: '../typo3conf/ext/myext/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/Grid03ThreeCol.png'}">
```

Clear cache from install tool and also from backend. And then check, it will work.

Comment: H vijay, thanks for your answer, but it won't work for me: `<flux:form id="grid03" options="{Fluidcontent: {sorting: 103}, group: 'LLL:typo3conf/ext/myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:grid.grids', icon: '../typo3conf/ext/myext/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/Grid03ThreeCol.png'}">` .. cache cleared , but I don't see the icons at the new content wizard

Comment: Just replace **"myext"** with your extension name from **'group'** and **'icon'** path at below line: ``<flux:form id="grid03" options="{Fluidcontent: {sorting: 103}, group: 'LLL:typo3conf/ext/myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:grid.grids', icon: '../typo3conf/ext/myext/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/Grid03ThreeCol.png'}">`` And it will display image only at "New content element" under your groupname (locallang.xlf:grid.grids) tab. it will not display under " Fluid Content type " in Page tab.

Comment: I know .. and I've chenged `myext`to my extension name, of course, but it's not working. I've also tried this, but Its the same: `... icon: '{f:uri.resource(path: \'img/icons/MyIcon.svg\')} ...`

Comment: edit: oha, it works. I see the icon at the page overview (Columns) - not at "New content element" under my groupname tab .. it's strange.

Comment: Yes, Its really strange...its Default TYPO3 CMS bug..Wait for next release...hope it may be solved...If you like my solution then pls..upvote..